# Why are these lines of code in python only outputting the same answer?

Tags: python, math

I'm trying to get this program to return all possible multiples of 3 and 5 below 1001 and then add them all together and print it but for some reason these lines of code only seem to be printing one number and that number is the number 2 which is obviously wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction to why this code is grossly wrong?

```
n = 0
x = n<1001
while (n < 1001):
     s = x%3 + x%5
     print s
```

Comment: x is a boolean value, you can't perform modulo on True

Answer (score 2):

You've got a few mistakes:

- x is a boolean type
- Your loop never ends
- adding values to mimic lists?

## Edit

Didn't see the part where you wanted sum, so you could employ a for-in loop or just a simple one like so:

```
sum = 0
for i in range(1001):
    if(i % 3 == 0 or i % 5):
        sum += i
print(sum)
```

(Python 3)

---

You need to stop while at some point by incrementing n. Here is some code:

```
nums = []
n = 0
while (n < 1001):
    # in here you check for the multiples
    # then append using nums.append()
    n += 1
```

This creates a loop and a list that accounts for every number in 0 to 1000. In the body, check for either condition and append to the list, then print out the values in the list.

`num` is a list where you are going to store all the values that apply, (those numbers who are divisible by 3 and 5, which you calculate with modulo). You append to that list when a condition is met. Here is some code:

```
nums = []
n = 0
while (n < 1001):
    if(n % 3 == 0 or n % 5 ==0):
        nums.append(n)
    n += 1
print(n) #or for loop for each value
```

Explanation: a list of numbers called `num` stores the numbers that are divisible by 3 or 5. The loop starts at zero and goes to 1000, and for all the values that are divisible by 3 or 5, they will be added to the list. Then it prints the list.

---

Of course there is a simpler approach with a range:

```
for i in range(1001):
    if(i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0):
        print(i)
```

This will print out all the values one by one. It is 1001 because the upper limit is exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

In your code: 
1.    `x=n<1001` - generates a boolean value; on which we can't perform a mathematical operation.

2. In while loop:
   your variable n,x are not changing; they are constant to same value for all the iterations.

Solution 1:
Below code will help you out.

```
s=0
for i in range(1,1002):
if( i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0):
    s = s + i
print(s)
```

Solution: 2 
There is one more approach you can use.

```
var = [i for i in range(1,1002) if i%3==0 or i%5 ==0]
print(sum(var))
```

Comment: s is a variable initialized to zero; else it will give error in the while loop that 's' is not defined.

Comment: But my code is much faster and consume lesser memory;
If we omit it; then how could we calculate the sum?

Comment: how ?
He needs the sum to be calculated.

Comment: In the very first line he said "...then add them all together and print it ..."

Answer (score 0):

```
true=1
false=0
```

so:

```
x = n<1001
```

we have x=1 because 0<1001 is true

```
s = x%3 + x%5
```

the remainder of 1/3 is 1 and 1/5 is 1